# Why do I have to add 7 when calculating how many bytes to allocate in order to store x amount of bits

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, computer-science, binary

So I'm using a programming language that always rounds down to the closest integer.
so `0.125 = 0`, `0.875 = 0`, `1.45 = 1` and `1.95 = 1`

Keeping that in mind, I can't use a formula like this `bits / 8` because if we have 3 bits and we try doing `3/8` we would get `0.375` and keeping what I mentioned previously about rounding down in mind, `0.375` would be `0`. 
 Same goes for `7/8`. It would give us `0.875` which rounds down to `0`. 
And that won't work because we need at least 1 byte to store bits from 1 to 7.

And in order to calculate how many bytes I need to allocate to store x amount of bits I use this formula.

Let's say we have 3 bits, doesn't matter what the value is.
`var bits = 3;`
I would then do `(bits + 7) / 8` which is `10/8` and that would yield `1.25`. And after it rounds down it gives us the perfect value which is `1`.

My question is as follows, I don't see why I have to add 7, why can't I add a value `1-6`? Technically for that example I could add `5`, because `5 + 3` yields the value `8` and `8 over 8` is `1`.

How come that adding the value `7` works for all values?

Comment: Maybe reading up on the [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) or the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) may shed some light on your issue.

Comment: That only explains why it rounds it off, I want to know why I'm adding 7 to it rather than another number.

Comment: Because sometimes $8$ bits is too many and $7=8-1$ is enough

Comment: You don't have to add 7 specifically.  You could, for example, add 7.4 and it would still do the job.

Comment: It works when you add $7$ because for $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+, m<n,$ we have $\left\lfloor\frac mn\right\rfloor=0$, but $\left\lfloor\frac {m+n-1}n\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac {m-1}n+1\right\rfloor=1$.